# What is the best practice for common data or process on django?

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to make a premium app in my Django project. 
Here is function on app. I just know what is the best practice.

Case 1. # using decorator with session

```
    ''' In custom decorator '''
    def get_premium_status():
        def decorator(func):
            def inner_decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
                #checking user status logic...

                request.session['premium'] = True

            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

         return wraps(func)(inner_decorator)
     return decorator


    ''' In app '''
    @get_premium_status() # using decorator with session
    function premium_bbs_list() {
        status = request.session["premium"]
        print status
    }

    @get_premium_status() # using decorator with session
    function premium_bbs_view() {
        status = request.session["premium"]
        print status
    }
```

Case 2. #call the function in view

```
    function get_premium_status()
        return True

    function premium_bbs_list() {
        status = get_premium_status()
        print status
    }

    function premium_bbs_view() {
        status = get_premium_status()
        print status
    }
```

Case 1 doesn't work. b/c Django session doesn't work if user isn't logged in.
Case 2 isn't fancy. I'd like use decorator. but I don't know how to fix first case.

Which one is the best case? and How can I fix it first case? 
or If you have any good best practice of this topic, Just Let me know any case.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You *can* force a user to login...

Answer (score 0):

If I were implementing this, I would consider writing [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs) to add an `is_premium` field to the `request`.

Comment: Could I get snippets or tutorial for this? I looked into it and googled. But I didn't fully understand. Thanks!

Comment: Snippets or tutorial for what, specifically? Is there something you're looking for that the documentation doesn't cover?

Comment: I mean... The doc doesn't have a example. I need a example for to add an is_premium field to the request on Middleware. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, ok — The Django Book has some good examples: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter17/

Comment: No problem. If it has been helpful, please give it (and the other helpful answers) an upvote. Also, please click the checkmark under the most helpful answer to mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of sessions don't depend on django.contrib.auth, it's vice versa. Thus session work with anonymous users.

But still using a session in this case does not feel right, because sessions were designed to save state between requests, not during a request. If you want to stick to a decorator pattern, you can add a custom attribute to request like this:

```
request._is_user_premium = True

from your view:
is_premium = getattr(request, '_is_user_premium', False)
```

But if I were you, I would implement this by encapsulating this logic in some kind of permission class:

```
class Permissions(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def has_premium_access():
        #implement your logic here and return a boolean
        return True

#view code
def myView(request):
    perm = Permissions(request)
    if perm.has_premium_access():
        #do stuff
    else:
        #do other stuff
```

(Just writing it off the top of my head, might have some syntax errors ;) )

But as David Wolever mentioned, it is also possible to implement this kind of logic in a middleware, just make sure you make your custom attribute lazy, so that you don't hit the database on every request if you only need this attribute only in some views.

Comment: As David Wolever mentioned, I've tested it using Middleware. As you know, It looks lazy. I'd consider this way. Thanks vkryachko.